# Change url replace in htaccess mysite.com/folder/desc+desc2+desc3/ to mysite.com/folder/desc-desc2-desc3/

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, replace

I am racking my brain and yet not obitive success, someone could help me..
Did you change the URL of my site, replace "+" by "-" in .htaccess

Is currently well:

mysite.com/folder/desc+desc2+desc3/

I would like to stay:

mysite.com/folder/desc-desc2-desc3/

Thank

Comment: Which is the URL you want people to enter and which do you want it to become internally? Or are you looking for a redirect? This needs more detail

Comment: Hi Damodaran,  Is currently well mysite.com/folder/desc+desc2+desc3/  
I would like to stay mysite.com/folder/desc-desc2-desc3/

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^(folder)/([^+]*)\++(.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.